# Python: Regarding variable scope. Why don't I need to pass x to Y?

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, scope

Consider the following code, why don't I need to pass x to Y?

```
class X:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

class Y:        
    def A(self):
        print(x.a,x.b,x.c)

x = X()
y = Y()
y.A()
```

---

Thank you to the top answers, they really helped me see what was the problem, namely misunderstanding regarding variable scope.  I wish I could choose both as correct answer as they are enlightening in their own way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [The Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces):

> Although scopes are determined statically, they are used dynamically.
>   At any time during execution, there are at least three nested scopes
>   whose namespaces are directly accessible:
>
> - the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names
> - the scopes of any enclosing functions, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also
> - non-global names the next-to-last scope contains the current module’s
> - global names the outermost scope (searched last) is the namespace containing built-in names

In your case `x=X()` puts `x` into the global namespace.  Since you did not define `x` locally in `Y.A`  (innermost scope), python searches for the variable definition using the above rules and finds that 'x' is defined in the outermost scope.  Therefore when you reference `x.a` in `Y.A` it resolves just fine.

Answer (score 8):

When python compiles a `def` into a function, it tries to figure out if the things you are referencing are locals - and if they're not, you must be referring to a global.  For example:

```
def f():
    print(x)
```

Well, you haven't defined `x` within the scope of `f`, so you must be referring to a global.

This is all that's happening in your above code.  You haven't defined `x` within the scope of `A`, so `x` must be a global.  As it happens, you define the global:

```
x = X()
```

before you call it:

```
y = Y()
y.A()
```

so everything works out okay.

In case you are going "hm, I'm not sure if I believe you, roippi" just look at the bytecode:

```
dis.dis(Y.A)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print) 
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x) # aha
              6 LOAD_ATTR                2 (a) 
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x) # aha!
             12 LOAD_ATTR                3 (b) 
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x) # aha!!
             18 LOAD_ATTR                4 (c) 
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            3 (3 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             24 POP_TOP              
             25 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

aha.

Answer (score 1):

It takes it from current scope. If you remove `x = X()` it will throw a error.

You can use variables from current scope and variable from all parent scopes inside a function.

```
def A():
   a = 1

   def B():
       b = 2

       def C():
          c= 3
          print(a,b,c)
```

For details on how scope is defined check python language reference on [Naming and Binding](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Also, since you are not changing x it works just fine. But if you would've try to change variable from parent scope it would throw error:

```
g= 0
def A():
   a = 1
   g = 2 #throws error
   def B():
       b = 2

       def C():
          c= 3
          print(a,b,c,d)
```

In such case you need to use `global` keyword:

```
g= 0
def A():
   a = 1

   global g
   g = 2 #does not throw error

   print(a,g)


A()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've instantiated x=X(), so that x.a, x.b, and x.c can be accessed. If you try z=X(), you'll notice it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Python looks up variables by first looking in the local scope (i.e. within a function) and if does not find it, it will use the variable from the global scope, if it exists. After that it will look for Python built-in names.

When the statement `y = Y()` is reached, `x` has already been declared in the global scope. This means that when the function `A(self)` is called, `x` can be looked up in the global scope.

More information about variable scope can be found here: [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)