# Python: Follow up regarding variable scope. Why can I change the global value of x.a within def A?

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, scope

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492835/python-regarding-variable-scope-why-dont-i-need-to-pass-x-to-y)

Why can I change the global value of `x.a` within `def A`? I am guessing it has to do with the fact that it is a class since it would not work with a regular variable because it would be redefined in the local scope of `def A`, but I am not quite understanding what is happening.

**Case 1**

```
class X:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

class Y:        
    def A(self):        
        print(x.a,x.b,x.c)
        x.a = 4           

x = X()
y = Y()
y.A()

print(x.a,x.b,x.c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Global names can be read within functions:

```
x = 5
def read_x():
    print(x)
```

Globals that reference mutable types can also be mutated within functions:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
def mutate_x():
    x[0] = 'One'
```

What you can't do to a global within the scope of a function is assignment:

```
x = 5
def set_x():
    # this simply assigns a variable named x local to this function -- it doesn't modify the global x
    x = 3
# now, back outside the scope of set_x, x remains 5
print(x)
5
```

Unless you explicitly declare the global within the scope of the function:

```
x = 5
def set_x():
    global x
    x = 3
# back outside the function's scope
print(x)
3
```

What you're doing in your example is "mutating" -- modifying an attribute of an object. Assigning a value to an attribute of a user-defined type is one example of mutation, just like modifying an element of a list or a dictionary. That's why this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `x = Y()` in `A` scope it would create a local `x` in that scope. In this case however, you are not setting `x`, you are setting `x.a`. **Looking up** variables takes into account global variables too. Imagine you are doing this instead `setattr(x, "a", 4)` and it will make more sense.

Also if I remember correctly you can "import" global variables into a function scope by using the `global` keyword. (see [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python))

Answer (score 0):

The class **A** doesn't have an init method that defines **x**, so the method **A**, when you try to access the attribute **a** of **x**, try to find the **x** object in the local scope, and since it can't find it then it looks the outside scope where an object name **x** is present, it grabs that object and override the attribute **a**.

So basically what you are doing is modify the actual attribute **a** of the object **x** that you create before you call **y.A()**.

It's the very basic foundation of a closure: access a variable that is defined outside the local scope.